# Sharepoint Web Part Page Problem (impossible to modify shared web part)

Tags: sharepoint

So I created this web part page on sharepoint, but everytime when I add a web part, the entire view gets squished into a narrow window. This makes it impossible to "modify shared web part" because all you can see on the menu pane are OK, Cancel and Apply. You can't fill in any detail or change anything from appearance to layout because you can't really see these options and put your mouse on them.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want help with determine why this happens, or if you just want to get rid of the faulting web part?

If the latter, you can access the web part admin page by adding ?contents=1 to the URL to remove the web part in question. 
This method is documented [documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263327(office.12).aspx).

```
http://<yourserverpath>/yourpage.aspx?contents=1
```

Comment: @Kelly, I have updated my answer with a link to where this method is documented.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTP:\\MySPRootSite/pages/default.aspx?ToolPaneView=2
```

This will help u to forcibly display the page in edit mode.

I am struck with forcibly editing a web part in the page after the page is displayed in edit mode.